# my Search method is coming up with all nulls

Tags: java, mysql, search, crud

Let me give a quick explanation. I took a 5 week course through a company on Java in July. They covered basic stuff, like console app, crud operations, mysql, and n-tier architecture. Since the course ended I didn't use it much because I went back to work, and other medical reasons surfaced....blah blah.

I was told by the company to make a simple program to reflect what I learned. Turns out I retained very little.

I decided to make a video game starage program. It would be used to stare your video games so you wouldn't have to search your bookcase(or how ever you store your games.)

It is a basic console app using the crud operations with MYSQL. I can't get my search function to actually work. I have 2 layers a Presentation layer and a Logic layer. The search method allows them to search for a game by the title. when i bring run the program and use Search it only displays the title and the rest is null. 
here is my Presentation layer:

```
private static Games SearchForGame() 
    {
    Logic aref = new Logic();
    Games g = new Games();
    Scanner scanline = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter the name of the game you wish to find:");
    g.setTitle(scanline.nextLine());
    aref.SearchGame();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Game Id:   " + g.getGameId());
    System.out.println("Title:     " + g.getTitle());
    System.out.println("Rating:    " + g.getRating());
    System.out.println("Platform:  "+ g.getPlatform());
    System.out.println("Developer: "+ g.getDeveloper());
    return g;
}
```

and here is my logic layer

```
public Games SearchGame() {
     Games g = new Games();
     try {
        Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url+dbName,userName,password);
        java.sql.PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT GameId,Title,Rating,Platform,Developer FROM games WHERE Title=?");
        statement.setString(1, g.getTitle());
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();

        while(rs.next()){

        g.setGameId(rs.getInt("GameId"));        
        g.setTitle(rs.getString("Title"));
        g.setRating(rs.getString("Rating"));
        g.setPlatform(rs.getString("Platform"));
        g.setDeveloper(rs.getString("Developer"));
        statement.executeUpdate();

         }
         } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
         }
         return g;
}
```

here is also my last results

```
Please enter the name of the game you wish to find:
 Skyrim

Game Id:   0
Title:     Skyrim
Rating:    null
Platform:  null
Developer: null
```

any help would be greatly appreciated and thanks in advance

---

EDIT: here is my code for my games class

```
 public class Games 
{
    public int GameId;
    public String Title;
    public String Rating;
    public String Platform;
    public String Developer;

    public int getGameId() 
    {
        return GameId;
    }

    public int setGameId(int gameId) 
    {
        return GameId = gameId;
    }

    public String getTitle() 
    {
        return Title;
    }

    public String setTitle(String title) 
    {
        return Title = title;
    }

    public String getRating() 
    {
        return Rating;
    }

    public void setRating(String rating) 
    {
        Rating = rating;
    }

    public String getPlatform() 
    {
        return Platform;
    }

    public void setPlatform(String platform) 
    {
        Platform = platform;
    }

    public String getDeveloper() 
    {
        return Developer;
    }

    public void setDeveloper(String developer) 
    {
        Developer = developer;
    }
```

}

Comment: I'd try to debug the application. Does `rs.getInt("GameId")` return anything? Is there data in the database?

Comment: Yeah there are at least 4 rows in my table

Comment: And they contain data for the other fields? Could you post the code for the `Games` class as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `SearchGame()` you create a new `Games` object, then you use `getTitle()` without even setting the title. In `SearchForGame()` you did set the title, but you should pass your `Games` object to `SearchGame()` and store the returned object. (`g` in `SearchGame()` and `g` in `SearchForGame()` are two different objects)